# Proxy Service with DTD

Tags: xml, proxy, wso2-esb

I have created a proxy service to receive the XML from the web. Works fine for the **XML with XSD** but fails when have **DOCTYPE** declaration with **DTD**.  I have added the parameter **'ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD'** but still see the errors. Any ideas?

**Proxy Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="cx.soa.poxRouter"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
  <target>
  <inSequence>
     <router>
        <route xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               expression="local-name(/env:Body/*)"
               match="Invoice">
           <target to="" soapAction="urn:process">
              <sequence>
                 <class name="cx.wso2.mediators.addNamespace">
                    <property name="nsToAdd" value="http://xmlns.ingram.com/invoice"/>
                 </class>
                 <log level="full"/>
                 <send>
                    <endpoint key="invoice.incoming.ingram.cxtec.prd.endpoint"/>
                 </send>
              </sequence>
           </target>
        </route>
        <route expression="true()">
           <target to="" soapAction="">
              <sequence>
                 <makefault version="soap11">
                    <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                          value="soap11Env:Server"/>
                    <reason value="Message Not Understood"/>
                    <role/>
                 </makefault>
                 <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
                 <send/>
              </sequence>
           </target>
        </route>
     </router>
  </inSequence>
</target>
<parameter name="ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD">true</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
<parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

**Sample Request XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.025/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="1429879833205-3629664823566250562@216.109.111.63"
timestamp="2015-04-24T05:50:33-07:00" version="1.2.025" xml:lang="en-US">
  <Header>      
  </Header>
  <Request deploymentMode="test">
  </Request>
</cXML>
```

**Error log:**

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-04-24 09:18:31,100] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder.processDocument(ApplicationXMLBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:91)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.TraceMessageBuilderDispatchHandler.build(TraceMessageBuilderDispatchHandler.java:73)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.TraceMessageBuilderDispatchHandler.invoke(TraceMessageBuilderDispatchHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with **Production support** of **WSO2 ESB** team, following are the list of options to make it work:

```
1. Enable DTD processing globally
```

If you are using message tracer, then you will have to enable the the DTD processing globally. Enable DTD processing globally by adding the following property to **'ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml'**.

```
<parameter name="ApplicationXMLBuilder.allowDTD">true</parameter>
```

**There is a security concern regarding enabling DTD processing in Apache Axis.** [DTD Security Concerns](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/core/security/CVE-2010-1632.pdf)

```
2. Disable message tracing
```

In a production environment, It's not recommend to enable the message tracing as it adds significant performance overhead. If we disable tracing, then the above issue wouldn't occur in the first place.

In our case, we had to **enable Message Tracing** for other reasons, so following the **case (1)** resolved the issue.